# Collection attribute is encoded as empty JSON in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a model class that looks like this:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder // lombok
public class MyClass {
    int id;
    String name;
    Set<String> hobbies;
}
```

I am creating the dataset using this method:

```java
MyClass myClassObj1 = MyClass.builder()
                            .id(1)
                            .name("Jack")
                            .hobbies(ImmutableSet.of("mountaineering", "cycling"))
                            .build();

MyClass myClassObj2 = MyClass.builder()
                            .id(2)
                            .name("Jill")
                            .hobbies(ImmutableSet.of("rhymes", "poetry"))
                            .build();

Dataset<MyClass> myClassDataset = 
        sparkSession.createDataset(
            ImmutableList.of(myClassObj1, myClassObj2), Encoders.bean(MyClass.class));
```

However, doing a `myClassDataset.show()` gives me an empty hobbies attribute like below:

```
+----------+-------+---------+
|id        |hobbies| name    |
+----------+-------+---------+
|         1|     {}|Jack     |
|         2|     {}|Jill     |
+----------+-------+---------+
```

`myClassDataset.schema()` gives this output:

```java
Seq(StructField(id,IntegerType,true), StructField(hobbies,Seq(),true), StructField(name,StringType,true))
```

Not sure why is the hobbies column shown as an empty Json?

Answer (score 0):

Here may be potential solution for you.

Spark's inability to handle complex objects (like a Set) directly with the default encoders. To resolve this, you'll need to implement a custom encoder to correctly handle the Set of hobbies.

##### 1. build custom encoder

```
public class MyClassEncoder {
    public static ExpressionEncoder<MyClass> encoder() {
        return Encoders.bean(MyClass.class);
    }

    public static Encoder<MyClass> customEncoder() {
        return Encoders.kryo(MyClass.class);
    }
}
```

##### 2. show dataset

```java
Dataset<MyClass> myClassDataset = sparkSession.createDataset(
                ImmutableList.of(myClassObj1, myClassObj2), MyClassEncoder.customEncoder());
```

##### Appendix

reponse for new issue

Q: This results in just one column"value" and it's value is some seemingly random ASCII characters. –

A:well , here is one more approach that `MyClass` implements interface Serializable and override toString method , like below

```java
    public String toString() {
        return "MyClass{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", hobbies=" + hobbies +  // here is json serialize sample 
                '}';
    }
```

here use a json framework slove json serialize, others approach is ok.

Comment: This results in just one column"value" and it's value is some seemingly random ASCII characters.

Comment: well , here is one more approach that ``MyClass```  implements interface ```Serializable``` and override ```toString``` method , like below 
```java
public String toString() {
        return "MyClass{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", hobbies=" + JSON.toJSONString(hobbies) +   // here is json serialize sample ,
                '}';
    }
```
here use a json framework slove json serialize, others approach is ok. not sure it could slove this issue  which your  encounter